# Unable to connect to wifi on HP Pavillian x360 with Intel Wireless 3165

Tags: networking, wireless, 16.04, intel-wireless

I'm using an I'm using an [HP Pavillion x360](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B014X4UAUI) which I'm using to dual boot Windows 10 and Ubuntu 16.04.1.  I am unable to connect to wifi and get the message "Wi-Fi networks - device not ready".

Regarding the wireless card:

```
$ lspci -v 

02:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wireless 3165 (rev 81)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Dual Band Wireless AC 3165
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 284
    Memory at a1500000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=8K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
    Kernel modules: iwlwifi

03:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8101/2/6E PCI Express Fast/Gigabit Ethernet controller (rev 0a)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company RTL8101/2/6E PCI Express Fast/Gigabit Ethernet controller
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 279
    I/O ports at 3000 [size=256]
    Memory at a1404000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
    Memory at a1400000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: r8169
    Kernel modules: r8169
```

And the firmware:

```
$ dmesg | grep iwl
[    2.439724] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Unsupported splx structure
[    2.442031] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-7265D-19.ucode failed with error -2
[    2.442051] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-7265D-18.ucode failed with error -2
[    2.442064] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-7265D-17.ucode failed with error -2
[    2.450123] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: loaded firmware version 16.242414.0 op_mode iwlmvm
[    2.483456] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Detected Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless AC 3165, REV=0x210
[    2.484097] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[    2.484797] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[    2.570741] ieee80211 phy0: Selected rate control algorithm 'iwl-mvm-rs'
[    2.804042] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0 wlp2s0: renamed from wlan0
[   13.007881] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[   13.008326] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[   13.070217] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[   13.070961] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[   73.007295] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[   73.007739] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[   73.069305] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[   73.069854] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[  423.161658] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[  423.162362] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[  423.223217] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[  423.223665] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
```

```
$ sudo ifconfig wlp2s0 up
$ ifconfig
enp3s0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr XX:XX:XX:XX:XX  
          inet addr:192.168.1.252  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::920a:95b2:5de4:bf07/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:9600 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:9313 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:7331669 (7.3 MB)  TX bytes:1522044 (1.5 MB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:1923 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:1923 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1 
          RX bytes:182547 (182.5 KB)  TX bytes:182547 (182.5 KB)

wlp2s0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
```

```
$ iwlist wlp2s0 scan
wlp2s0    No scan results
```

The `ifconfig wlp2s0 up` succeeds but then I'm still not connected although the device shows up in the output from `ifconfig`

```
$ ls /lib/firmware/iwlwifi-*.ucode
/lib/firmware/iwlwifi-1000-5.ucode     /lib/firmware/iwlwifi-6000g2b-6.ucode
/lib/firmware/iwlwifi-100-5.ucode      /lib/firmware/iwlwifi-6050-5.ucode
/lib/firmware/iwlwifi-105-6.ucode      /lib/firmware/iwlwifi-7260-10.ucode
/lib/firmware/iwlwifi-135-6.ucode      /lib/firmware/iwlwifi-7260-12.ucode
/lib/firmware/iwlwifi-2000-6.ucode     /lib/firmware/iwlwifi-7260-13.ucode
/lib/firmware/iwlwifi-2030-6.ucode     /lib/firmware/iwlwifi-7260-16.ucode
/lib/firmware/iwlwifi-3160-10.ucode    /lib/firmware/iwlwifi-7260-7.ucode
/lib/firmware/iwlwifi-3160-12.ucode    /lib/firmware/iwlwifi-7260-8.ucode
/lib/firmware/iwlwifi-3160-13.ucode    /lib/firmware/iwlwifi-7260-9.ucode
/lib/firmware/iwlwifi-3160-16.ucode    /lib/firmware/iwlwifi-7265-10.ucode
/lib/firmware/iwlwifi-3160-7.ucode     /lib/firmware/iwlwifi-7265-12.ucode
/lib/firmware/iwlwifi-3160-8.ucode     /lib/firmware/iwlwifi-7265-13.ucode
/lib/firmware/iwlwifi-3160-9.ucode     /lib/firmware/iwlwifi-7265-16.ucode
/lib/firmware/iwlwifi-3165-13.ucode    /lib/firmware/iwlwifi-7265-8.ucode
/lib/firmware/iwlwifi-3165-9.ucode     /lib/firmware/iwlwifi-7265-9.ucode
/lib/firmware/iwlwifi-3945-2.ucode     /lib/firmware/iwlwifi-7265D-10.ucode
/lib/firmware/iwlwifi-4965-2.ucode     /lib/firmware/iwlwifi-7265D-12.ucode
/lib/firmware/iwlwifi-5000-5.ucode     /lib/firmware/iwlwifi-7265D-13.ucode
/lib/firmware/iwlwifi-5150-2.ucode     /lib/firmware/iwlwifi-7265D-16.ucode
/lib/firmware/iwlwifi-6000-4.ucode     /lib/firmware/iwlwifi-8000C-13.ucode
/lib/firmware/iwlwifi-6000g2a-5.ucode  /lib/firmware/iwlwifi-8000C-16.ucode
/lib/firmware/iwlwifi-6000g2a-6.ucode
```

EDIT:

I changed the regulatory domain to be in the US.  I then updated the firmware:

```
cd /lib/firmware
sudo wget https://github.com/OpenELEC/iwlwifi-firmware/raw/master/firmware/iwlwifi-7265D-21.ucode
```

After which it still seemed to be the same version

```
$ dmesg | grep iwl[    2.412145] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Unsupported splx structure
[    2.421728] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-7265D-19.ucode failed with error -2
[    2.421751] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-7265D-18.ucode failed with error -2
[    2.421762] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-7265D-17.ucode failed with error -2
[    2.442843] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: loaded firmware version 16.242414.0 op_mode iwlmvm
[    2.477265] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Detected Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless AC 3165, REV=0x210
[    2.477778] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[    2.478369] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[    2.609426] ieee80211 phy0: Selected rate control algorithm 'iwl-mvm-rs'
[    2.789597] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0 wlp2s0: renamed from wlan0
[   13.011549] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[   13.011996] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[   13.072847] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[   13.073398] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled

$ rfkill list all
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: acer-wireless: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: no
4: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no

$ uname -r
4.4.0-31-generic
```

Comment: Especially note the firmware update in the duplicate.

Comment: @chili555 i set the regulatory domain, updated the firmware, rebooted and still cannot connect ("Wi-Fi Networks device not ready")

Comment: And how about the changes in the router? Any changes here? `dmesg | grep iwl`?

Comment: @chili555 It is in WPA2-AES.  I didn't play around with any of the other settings but this machine connects fine using windows so I don't imagine that would be the problem.  Also `dmesg | grep iwl` shows no change

Comment: Including the firmware?

Comment: @chili555 yes, exactly the same

Comment: It loads the -16 firmware still? What is the result of: `rfkill list all`? And also: `uname -r`

Comment: @chili555 outputs are in the recent edit

Comment: Let's try -17 instead: `cd /lib/firmware` and then: `sudo wget https://github.com/OpenELEC/iwlwifi-firmware/raw/master/firmware/iwlwifi-7265D-17.ucode` Reboot. Any improvement?

Comment: @chili555 Looks like this time the firmware update took, `[    2.318070] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: loaded firmware version 17.265642.0 op_mode iwlmvm` but I still get device not ready.  `rfkill list all` and `uname -r` show the same output

Comment: I have reopened the question. Please provide the diagnostics as outlined here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos/425180#425180 Paste the result here: http://paste.ubuntu.com Give us the link in your response.

Comment: http://paste.ubuntu.com/21842931/ Thanks again for all your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please note in your paste:

```
1: acer-wireless: Wireless LAN  
Soft blocked: yes   
Hard blocked: no
```

And also:

```
hp_wmi                 16384  0
acer_wmi               20480  0
```

Your computer is not *both* an Acer and an HP! Let's unload and blacklist the *acer-wmi* module.

```
sudo -i
modprobe -r acer-wmi
echo "blacklist acer-wmi"  >>  /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
exit
```

Your wireless should now be working, but it might take a reboot.

Comment: Following this and a reboot the "Enable Wireless" option has disappeared when I click on Network Manager.  Also: 
`$ rfkill list
0: hci0: Bluetooth
 Soft blocked: no
 Hard blocked: no`

Comment: Did the driver module load? `lsmod | grep iwl` If not load it: `sudo modprobe iwlwifi` Any errors or clues here? `dmesg | grep iwl` As before: http://paste.ubuntu.com and give us the link.

Comment: not sure what happened but I turned my machine back on to try this and the wifi worked!  Thanks so much for all your help

Comment: Awesome! Glad it's working.

Answer (score 1):

chili555's answer worked for me as well! Too new to comment, but I think it is important to let folks know this answer worked for more than one person on the same machine with the same hardware. I also tried the following which worked...

```
sudo -s
pico /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-ua-acer-wmi.conf
(Add the following content)
blacklist acer-wmi (save and close file)
init 6 (to restart)
```