# No wireless connection in HP x360 Convertible

Tags: wireless, 16.10, hp

I installed Ubuntu 16.10 on my HP x360 convertible laptop and have tried all possible solutions available, but my wireless connection is not working. It does show the 'enable wifi' option in the wifi toggle menu, but does not show any connections.

[image]

Comment: make sure your wireless switch/button has been set to enabled. I believe on HP laptops this is indicated by a white LED light (as opposed to orange which denotes disabled)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to connect to wifi on HP Pavillian x360 with Intel Wireless 3165](http://askubuntu.com/questions/805383/unable-to-connect-to-wifi-on-hp-pavillian-x360-with-intel-wireless-3165)